# Scrape content of heading tag

Tags: php, html

I want to fetch the content of the heading tag given below:

```
<h1 style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: white; line-height: 2em; margin:0 .5em .2em .5em; padding: 4px 8px 4px 8px; border-radius: 10px;-moz-border-radius: 10px; -webkit-border-radius: 10px; border: 1px solid silver;text-decoration:none; font-size: 2.1em;">Seminar Report</h1><div style='position:relative; visibility:visible; width:100%; overflow:auto;' align='center'>
```

Can I do it using `file_get_html()` or `file_get_contents()`?

This is what i am getting when I use `var_dump($html);`

```
object(simple_html_dom)#1 (23) { ["root"]=> object(simple_html_dom_node)#2 (9) { ["nodetype"]=> int(5) ["tag"]=> string(4) "root" ["attr"]=> array(0) { } ["children"]=> array(2) { [0]=> object(simple_html_dom_node)#3 (9) { ["nodetype"]=> int(2) ["tag"]=> string(7) "comment" ["attr"]=> array(0) { } ["children"]=> array(0) { } ["nodes"]=> array(0) { } ["parent"]=> RECURSION ["_"]=> array(2)
```

and so on

and when I use var_dump($html->find('h1'));I get

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(simple_html_dom_node)#48 (9) { ["nodetype"]=> int(1) ["tag"]=> string(2) "h1" ["attr"]=> array(1) { ["style"]=> string(233) "BACKGROUND-COLOR: white; line-height: 2em; margin:0 .5em .2em .5em; padding: 4px 8px 4px 8px; border-radius: 10px;-moz-border-radius: 10px; -webkit-border-radius: 10px; border: 1px solid silver;text-decoration:none; font-size: 2.1em;" } ["children"]=> array(0) { } ["nodes"]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(simple_html_dom_node)#49 (9) { ["nodetype"]=> int(3) ["tag"]=> string(4) "text" ["attr"]=> array(0) { } ["children"]=> array(0) { } ["nodes"]=> array(0) { } ["parent"]=> *RECURSION* ["_"]=> array(1) { [4]=> string(14) "Seminar Report" } ["tag_start"]=> int(0) ["dom":"simple_html_dom_node":private]=> object(simple_html_dom)#1 (23) { ["root"]=> object(simple_html_dom_node)#2 (9) { ["nodetype"]=> int(5) ["tag"]=> string(4) "root" ["attr"]=> array(0) { } ["children"]=> array(2) { [0]=> object(simple_html_dom_node)#3 (9) { ["nodetype"]=> int(2) ["tag"]=> string(7) "comment" ["attr"]=> array(0) { } ["children"]=> array(0) { } ["nodes"]=> array(0) { } ["parent"]=> *RECURSION* ["_"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [4]=> string(23) "" }
```

Comment: You'd need to give your heading a unique id. For example `<h1 id="myHeading">Heading Text</h1>

Comment: @scotty3785 What if he doesn't have the control to edit?

Comment: Then he'd have to iterate through each h1 object hoping to find the correct one.

Comment: it is an external webpage I can't control it. But this is the only h1 tag used there.

Comment: @RajaPanda Answer me. Let's solve it together. `:)`

Comment: Could you share URL of site?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it will be easy to use [`file_get_html($url)`](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#fragment-13):

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');
echo $html->find('h1')->plaintext;
```

**Notes**

- Make sure you have SimpleHTMLDom Library added.
- The above code uses `http://www.google.com/` as sample. You should replace it with your URL.
- The above code gets only the first `<h1>`'s text output.

Comment: I am getting this 
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp3\htdocs\scarp.php on line 5

Comment: @RajaPanda Tell me what's the value of `var_dump()` on that object which you are trying? So if it is `$html`, tell me the output of `var_dump($html)`...

Comment: object(simple_html_dom)#1 (23) { ["root"]=> object(simple_html_dom_node)#2 (9) { ["nodetype"]=> int(5) ["tag"]=> string(4) "root" ["attr"]=> array(0) { } ["children"]=> array(2) { [0]=> object(simple_html_dom_node)#3 (9) { ["nodetype"]=> int(2) ["tag"]=> string(7) "comment" ["attr"]=> array(0) { } ["children"]=> array(0) { } ["nodes"]=> array(0) { } ["parent"]=> *RECURSION* ["_"]=> array(2)  

and so on

Comment: @RajaPanda Thanks. Can you kindly update in your original question not in the comments? Look there's an **edit** button under your question.

Comment: I have added the contents of var_dump but not the whole content since it was very large.

Comment: @RajaPanda Tell me what do you get for `$html->find('h1')`?